# Table cell with fixed height and display of some buttons on hover-over

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

First a link to a Demo-Site:
http://lustigelanguste.de/eventpoll/eventpoll.php?id=6512bd43d9caa6e02c990b0a82652dca

This problem only occurs on Google-Chrome. Firefox and IE seem to work just fine ...

As you can see, Chrome changes the height of the table cells if there's a long name on the last row before the data-input row (in this case: the row with "WWWWWWW...." at the beginning).

I'd like every row set to the same height though. I already tried to give the child DIV a max-height property and set overflow:hidden;, and it kind of works, but then my hover-over-buttons can't be displayed any more.

Code for the table (excerpt):

```
<td id="auswahlname">
    <div class="hoverbuttons">'.$auswahl["Namen"].'
        <span class="showbuttons">
            <form method="post" action="./eventpoll.php">
                <input type="submit" class="delbutton" name="auswahlentfernen" value="entfernen" title="Das L&ouml;schen einer Auswahl ist unwiderruflich.">
                <input type="submit" class="editbutton" name="auswahledit" title="Auswahl editieren" value="edit">
            </form>
        </span>
    </div>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
DIV.contentwithtopnav table {
    margin-top:40px; 
    margin-bottom:40px;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    background-color:#FFFFFF; 
    empty-cells:hide; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(102, 123, 150, 0.5);
}

DIV.contentwithtopnav td    {   
        padding:10px; 
        text-align:left; 
    }

DIV.contentwithtopnav tr    {   
        padding:10px;
    }

SPAN.showbuttons {  
        float: left;
        margin-left: -5em;
        opacity:0;
    }

DIV.hoverbuttons:hover .showbuttons {
        opacity:1;
    }

SPAN.showbuttons:hover { 
        opacity:1;
    }
```

Any Idea how I can fix this in Google Chrome? Let me know if you need any additional information.

Thanks!

Comment: First of all try to correct all you HTML errors... http://validator.w3.org/check , maybe this will help, if not let me know I will check.

Comment: this php excerpt is part of a php-echo statement. So '.$auswahl["Namen"].' is not an error, and it works just fine in FF and IE ;) And the id that is set on the "td" element hasn't got any CSS that refers to it yet. I'm fixing the HTML errors now anyways :D.